# Problems linking Team City with Bit Bucket Cloud

Tags: teamcity, bitbucket

I am having problems linking Bit Bucket with Team City

When I test a VCS route that was working a while ago I now get the error

```
Test connection failed in Build Experiments :: Experimental
List remote refs failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: 
https://bitbucket.org/COMPANY/REPOSITORY.git: git-upload-pack not permitted
```

Has anyone ever had this?

I have tried to regenerate the keys and reauthorise but nothing works

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what caused this I restarted the whole process and it worked!